# Linking against a specific shared library version in linux

Tags: linux, build-process, linker

My build process consists of Qt's qmake Makefile generator and the typical make utility bundled with linux.
My application consists of a few shared libraries and the main application is linked against them.
How can I apply the typical linux versioning scheme on my libraries? (Use version 2 -> link against foo.so.2 that points to foo.so.2.y.z with an ldconfig generated link).

The answer doesn't have to be specific for my build process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your library should be named `libfoo.so.2.y.z`, with symlinks of `libfoo.so.2` and `libfoo.so` both pointing to that. The library should be created using `-soname libfoo.so.2` in the linker command line (or `-Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.2` on the gcc command line).

Hope that helps!